# Pandas memory usage and memory allocation

Tags: python, pandas, csv, memory, out-of-memory

I'm trying to analyze a big csv (the csv is ~3GB and ~6 milions rows) using pandas (my computer has 32GB of RAM memory) and for a series of reasons I cannot load it in chunks. I can read the csv without any problems but as soon as I start to clean the file the whole script crashes. Monitoring the memory usage of my computer I found that just to have the csv stored in a pandas DataFrame 50% of my RAM (18GB) is used. As soon as I start modifying the DataFrame the memory usage skyrockets to 100% and crashed my script. Using the DataFrame methos `memory_usage(deep=True)` I find that my DataFrame is 3GB for pandas. But how is it possible that pandas tells me that my variable is 3GB while my memory usage is at 18GB (maybe 13GB since %GB are used by the OS)?

This is an example:

```
raw = pd.read_csv("db.csv", sep="\t", on_bad_lines="skip", dtypes="object")

remove_invalid_ateco = lambda df_: df_[df_.ateco.str.contains("\.")]
months_diff = lambda a, b: 12 * (a.year - b.dt.year) + (a.month - b.dt.month)
raw.query(
            "~piva.isnull() and"
            "~code.isnull() and "
            "provincia_cd.str.len() == 2"
        )
        .pipe(remove_invalid_ateco)
        .assign(
            # Float
            roe=lambda df_: df_.roe.str.replace(",", "."),
            roi=lambda df_: df_.roi.str.replace(",", "."),
            ros=lambda df_: df_.ros.str.replace(",", "."),
            longitudine_dd=lambda df_: df_.longitudine_dd.str.replace(",", "."),
            latitudine_dd=lambda df_: df_.latitudine_dd.str.replace(",", "."),
            sfin=lambda df_: df_.sfin.str.replace(",", "."),
            cap_del=lambda df_: df_.cap_del.str.replace(
                ",", "."
            ),
            cap_sott=lambda df_: df_.cap_sott.str.replace(
                ",", "."
            ),
            cap_vers=lambda df_: df_.cap_vers.str.replace(",", "."),
            eq_ec_1=lambda df_: df_.eq_ec_1.str.replace(",", "."),
            eq_eff_1=lambda df_: df_.eq_eff_1.str.replace(",", "."),
            eq_fin_1=lambda df_: df_.eq_fin_1.str.replace(",", "."),
            eq_liq_1=lambda df_: df_.eq_liq_1.str.replace(",", "."),
            eq_pat_1=lambda df_: df_.eq_pat_1.str.replace(",", "."),
            # Date
            date_iscr=lambda df_: pd.to_datetime(
                df_.date_iscr, errors="coerce"
            ),
            date_init=lambda df_: pd.to_datetime(
                df_.date_init, errors="coerce"
            ),
            delta=lambda df_: months_diff(
                datetime.today(), pd.to_datetime(df_.date_init, errors="coerce")
            ),
        )
```

Comment: You should probably show some code. For all we can guess, the "modifying the DataFrame" bit takes 8 copies of your data.

Comment: Post your code. Most tweeks are around improving your code to be faster and more memory efficient

Comment: I added some code

Comment: I'd keep in mind that every new variable is storing more data and by the looks of it won't release that memory till the .assign finishes. I've never worked with assign but I would thi k that if you could apply your chances directly to the df then that would help as ram would only increase to process and maybe store new data you've created

Comment: You'd probably have a better time removing the rows that you don't need in-place first before moving on to mangling in `assign`. You can also use `decimal=','` for `read_csv` so you don't need to convert those yourself at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use a library of mine - **convtools**, there's `Table` helper ([docs](https://convtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tables.html) | [github](https://github.com/westandskif/convtools)) which allows to process table data as a stream.

Caveats:

1. since there's no `db.csv` sample, I cannot test it properly
2. `pd.read_csv` supports `decimal=','` parameter, so better use it. But I'm still replicating your code behavior so you can use it in other cases (e.g stripping commas - group separators)
3. the code bellow doesn't do any `on_bad_lines="skip"`.

```py
from convtools import conversion as c
from convtools.contrib.tables import Table


float_cols = ["roe", "roi", "ros", "longitudine_dd", "latitudine_dd", "sfin", "cap_del", "cap_sott", "cap_vers", "eq_ec_1", "eq_eff_1", "eq_fin_1", "eq_liq_1", "eq_pat_1"]
date_cols = ["date_iscr", "date_init"]


def months_diff(a, b):
    return 12 * (a.year - b.year) + (a.month - b.month)


def parse_datetime(value, default):
    try:
        return datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d")
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        return default


rows_iter = (
    Table.from_csv(
        "db.csv", header=True, dialect=Table.csv_dialect(delimiter="\t")
    )
    .filter(
        c.and_(
            c.col("piva").is_not(None),
            c.col("code").is_not(None),
            c.col("provincia_cd").pipe(len) == 2,
            c("\.").not_in(c.col("ateco")),
        )
    )
    .update(
        **{
            column: c.col(column).call_method("replace", ",", ".")
            for column in float_cols
        },
        **{
            column: c.call_func(parse_datetime, c.col(column), default=None)
            for column in date_cols
        },
    )
    .update(
        delta=c.col("date_init").and_then(
            c.call_func(months_diff, date.today(), c.this)
        )
    )
    .into_iter_rows(dict)
)
```

The result is an iterable of dicts, which you can feed directly to `pd.DataFrame` or `polars` (whatever).